# ¿Como hacer un update con where a una tabla temporal de tipo varibale?

Tags: sql

[image: Consulta SQl]

Este es mi consulta inserto las entradas, y quiero realizar un update utilizando el where

Answer (score 0):

Tienes varias formas de resolver el caso, una de las más simples es renombrar la columna 'ProductoID' -en la subconsulta- para evitar nombrar la tabla sin caer en ambigüedad.

```
...FROM (
SELECT produc.ProductoID AS id, SUM(...
) AS rg
WHERE ProductoID = rg.id...
```

Comment: Oh muy bien ya me avía topado con eso pero no recordaba, Gracias Saludos